# Keyboard input vs Barcode Input

Tags: barcode, barcode-scanner, jquery-barcode

I have a textbox that shows only numbers

```
    <input type="number" min="0" max="999999999999999999" maxlength="1">
```

and I have a barcode scanner

now

the thins is that when I type on my keyboard I can only type 1 character and it will show 1 character on the textbox but I am having trouble in the barcode scanner because when I scan on the scanner it only shows 1 character on the text box and I need the whole barcode

can someone please help me on the codes

*note: there should only be one textbox

Comment: change the maxlength to a apt integer

Answer (score 1):

you've set the maxlength of the input to maxlength="1" - which means that this input can't have more than 1 character - not matter if the source is keyboard or barcode scanner (barcode scanner eventually emulates keyboard input). you need to remove that.

**EDIT**

as a work around please check this out... what I've done here is measure the time a key stroke takes. measure the time of a keyboard and compare is to the time it take the barcode scanner. if I'm correct then the barcode scanner should be much lower then the keyboard:

```
<input type="text" onkeydown="checkKeyDown(this)" onkeyup="checkKeyUp(this)" />
<script>
    var keyDownTime;

    function checkKeyDown(obj) {
        keyDownTime = new Date();
    };

    function checkKeyUp(obj) {
        var now = new Date();
        alert(now - keyDownTime);
    };
</script>
```

Comment: I got your point but what I was trying to do is that limit the keyboard input to just 1 char and write the whole characters of the barcode with 1 click of the scanner

Comment: well, I don't think you'll be able to achieve it doing that because the input box doesn't know how to separate key strokes from barcode input. I'm about to edit my answer with what might be a workaround - you'll have to check it against your barcode scanner since I don't have one.

Comment: actually the keyboard is the one who is lower than the barcode...I tested the code you have given and it very close but if you can edit it with the barcode having more char than the keyboard... then I appreciate it more

Comment: try to test is with console.log instead of the alert I wrote - might be different results

Comment: @user3064490 and what if the barcode scanner breaks and you have to manually type the barcode in...

Comment: well @richsage i said that to my boss and he said it is not my concern..  I just told that cheating was happening with the attendance.. the worker(who is absent) can be logged in by his friend(who is present)... they use barcodes for attendance and they want to limit the keyboard typing by one and use the barcode scanner to scan their barcode for attendance

Comment: @user3064490 if it's for that use, why don't you use a finger print reader? http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_sacat=0&_from=R40&_nkw=usb+finger+print+reader&_nkwusc=usb+finger+prin+reader&_rdc=1

Comment: @user3064490 this sounds less like an HTML issue and more like a management issue ;-) regardless, as has been pointed out, a barcode scanner is just a keyboard device essentially, so perhaps removing the physical keyboard might be a better option :-)

Comment: +1 This because it allows a programmer to tell the difference between barcode input with low lag (<5ms) vs human keyboard input (>30 ms).